# How to get only the filtered data from Prisma / GraphQL query

Tags: graphql, prisma

I have 2 sets of data (***users*** and ***events***) in many-to-many relation.
I am using the following query to retrieve and filter the data.

```
{
  events(
    where: {
      AND: [
        { location: { name: "Test" } }
        {
          time: {
            startDate_lt: "2018-12-03T13:46:13.021Z"
            endDate_gt: "2018-12-03T13:46:13.021Z"
          }
        }
        {
          participantList_some: {
            participant: { firstName: "Lorem", lastName: "Ipsum" }
          }
        }
      ]
    }

  ) {
    participantList {
      participant {
        firstName
        lastName
      }
    }
    location {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

So far so good, I'm getting the following outcome:

```
{
  "data": {
    "events": [
      {
        "participantList": [
          {
            "participant": {
              "firstName": "Chuck",
              "lastName": "Norris"
            }
          },
          {
            "participant": {
              "firstName": "Lorem",
              "lastName": "Ipsum"
            }
          }
        ],
        "location": {
          "name": "Test"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I'd like to have would be to get only the participant that I've filtered, ie. "Lorem Ipsum". This way I'm getting all the (2) participants from that event.
So my desired outcome would be:

```
{
  "data": {
    "events": [
      {
        "participantList": [
          {
            "participant": {
              "firstName": "Lorem",
              "lastName": "Ipsum"
            }
          }
        ],
        "location": {
          "name": "Test"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

At the moment I'm filtering out the unwanted data from code. I've searched how or if I can do this with a query or additional parameters but didn't find something useful. Any help or guide is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a filter to any field of the request. Which means you can filter the participants in your found events:

```
{
  events(
    where: {
      AND: [
        { location: { name: "Test" } }
        {
          time: {
            startDate_lt: "2018-12-03T13:46:13.021Z"
            endDate_gt: "2018-12-03T13:46:13.021Z"
          }
        }
        {
          participantList_some: {
            participant: { firstName: "Lorem", lastName: "Ipsum" }
          }
        }
      ]
    }

  ) {
    participantList (where: { participant: { firstName: "Lorem", lastName: "Ipsum" } }) {
      participant {
        firstName
        lastName
      }
    }
    location {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Errorname for the answer, however I'm getting an error when I add that **where** statement. It says `"Cannot return null for non-nullable type (line 4, column 7):\n      participant(where: {firstName: \"Lorem\", lastName: \"Ipsum\"})`.

Comment: Oh. It seems that this would conflict with your schema. Could you provide the relevant part of your schema?

Comment: It actually worked by adding the **where** condition at `participantList` level, like this:

`participantList(where: { participant: { firstName: "Lorem", lastName: "Ipsum" } }) `